# Core Data - NSFetchedResultsController bug

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

It seems controllerDidChangeContent: is being called as soon as I create a new managed object in my context. The documentation seems to suggest this method is called only once you save: the context.

This "bug" if it is one, is causing my application to crash because as part of my table view cell, I need to load other managed objects that don't exist at the time of creating the main managed object.

Someone seems to have spotted this too, please check out the following link and I would love to hear your opinions on this: http://openradar.appspot.com/10207615

---

**More information**

Although the link I added to this post showcases an example using two NSManagedObjectContext, my application is using one context, but the controllerDidChangeContent: is being messaged none the less as soon as an object is created in the one and only context, and controllerDidChangeContent: is being called a second time when I save: this context. It is to my understanding that this method should only be messaged when the context is saved.

Comment: Did you check by stepping through the code with breakpoints?

Comment: Yes I did and as soon as a chunk of code that creates a managed object had been executed, controllerDidChangeContent: is being messaged. Have a look at the link, it demonstrates this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to avoid dealing with more than one managedObjectContext. If your cell needs to load other managed objects, it should still use the same managed object context as the main managed object.

I have yet to see a use case where it is absolutely unavoidable to use more than one managed object context referring to the same model active at the same time.

Comment: Hi Mundi, I am actually only using one context in my application, created in the app delegate and passed around via references. I updated the post accordingly.